# Arc lint error on a new Go Service with an error in parsing output

Tags: lint, golint

While Running arc lint on a service

I am seeing this error

```
 Exception 
    Some linters failed:
- Exception: Linter failed to parse output!

  STDOUT


  STDERR
  <standard input>:40:1: expected statement, found 'package'
  <standard input>:59:27: expected ';', found error

(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
```

It suddenly started happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. Here was the observation to fix the same. Whenever you do execute `lint` it automatically adjusts the code accordingly. In case if the new line is not present in the end of the file, `lint` copied the entire file so code become like below

```
package mypackage

import (
    "go.uber.org/fx"
)

// Module is an FX module used when initializing the app
var Module = fx.Provide(
    NewNewClient,
package mypackage

import (
    "go.uber.org/fx"
)

// Module is an FX module used when initializing the app
var Module = fx.Provide(
    NewNewClient,
)
```

Note that package is repeated here hence cause the issue.